# Add Path to JPGs in Attribute Table based on Unique ID

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, arcgis-pro, python-3

I've been tasked with updating attribute table fields with file paths to image files in a folder based on a unique ID. I'm having trouble thinking up a script that will do this? I'm working on a standalone script in ArcGIS Pro 2.3.1 Arcpy.

This is an example of how the table should look. Every JPG has a unique ID that matches the Post_Number field unique ID. Currently, the paths to the JPGs are entered manually into the table, and there are 1000s of them.

[image]

I don't think a Calculate Field will work because not all JPGs are stored in the same directory. All I've done so far is create a cursor that searches the Post_Number and Photo fields.

`#for each row print the fields
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            print(u"{0}, {1}".format(row[0], row[1]))`

Comment: Create a tool with 1st parameter = raster dataset, multiple. Do search in Windows explorer, select results, drag and drop them to parameter box. Hope the rest is obvious - extact id from file name to make join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because my reputation implies in comment limits I need to assume you already had the 'Post_Number' field filled when the geometry for a photo is created, so the script below just search for the photos and fills the 'Photo' field with the full path:

```
import fnmatch
import os

# Directory/unity where search begins
src = 'C:\\'

# List of files with complete path and filename
matches = []
rowM = [None, None]

# Counters for log purposes
count1 = 0
count2 = 0

print 'Beginning search of photos'

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src):
    count1 += 1
    print count1
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.jpg'):
        count2 += 1
        rowM[0] = os.path.join(root, filename) # complete path
        rowM[1] = os.path.join(filename[:-4]) # filename without extension
        matches.append(list(rowM))

import arcpy

fc = 'C:\Teste\Teste.gdb\Teste_pto'
fields = ['Post_Number', 'Photo']
expression = fields[1] + ' IS NULL'

print 'Beginning search of paths'

try:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (fc, fields, expression) as uc:
        for line in uc:
            for row in matches:
                if (line[0] == row[1]): # if Post_Number matches filename
                    line[1] = row[2] # Photo is equal to path
                    uc.updateRow(line)
except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    arcpy.AddMessage(str(arcpy.GetMessages(2)))


print 'End of script'
```

Comment: thanks for the post. Where is `fnmatch` defined? And, yes, the `Post_Number` field is already filled.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7, and fnmatch is a module (note the first line). More information in Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html

Comment: It runs through without error, but the `Photo` field in the table doesn't get populated.

Comment: Are you using a normal gdb or a sde connection? If you are using a sde connection, it can be necessary to start a edit session. Use a try:
    update code
except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    arcpy.AddMessage(str(arcpy.GetMessages(2))) structure to see the error messages.

Comment: Lucas,

I wasn't sure what the purpose of `expression` variable was so I removed it. Then your script worked fine.

Comment: Good. The difference is: with expression, only the rows with null value in 'Photo' are processed in the update cursor; without expression, the script runs a update in ALL rows of your fc.

Answer (score 1):

This script worked well too:

```
import arcpy, os

ws = r'pathTo\JPGsdirectory'
jpgs = {} # empty dictionary

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(ws): #iterate the directory
    for fname in fileList:
        jpgs[fname[:-4]] = os.path.join(dirName,fname) #create key:value pairs dictionary

fc = r'pathTo\featureclass\WCDOT_Signs'
fields = ['OID@', 'Post_Number', 'Photo']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        try:
            row[2] = jpgs[row[1]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        except KeyError:
            print("No photo for: {}".format(row[1]))

del cursor
```